# How to programmatically call Eclipse format on a specific java file within a plugin handler?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am wrting an Eclipse plugin that rewrites java files (possibly multiple files) based on the content of a selected java file (right click -> custom menu item).

Everything works as intended but the rewriting of the files doesn't manage the content formating so after using the plugin I have to manually format each affected java files with the Eclipse format action.

I am able to programmatically call the Eclipse format action on the selected java file but i'd like to also format all other files.

Here's what I have right now (the part that should change is within the for loop):

```
@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException
{
    var workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    var activeWorkbenchWindow = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    var selection = activeWorkbenchWindow.getActivePage().getSelection();

    List<String> generatedClasses = null;

    if ((selection instanceof IStructuredSelection structuredSelection)
            && (structuredSelection.getFirstElement() instanceof ICompilationUnit compilationUnit))
    {
        try
        {

            var projectClassLoader = getProjectClassLoader(compilationUnit.getJavaProject());
            generatedClasses = bindingGenerator.generateBindings(compilationUnit, projectClassLoader);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | IOException
                | IllegalClassFormatException | JavaModelException e)
        {
            // TODO pop an error message dialog?
            return null;
        }

        for (String generatedClass : generatedClasses)
            try
            {
                // I can find the IType of each affected java file here if it should help?
                var type = compilationUnit.getJavaProject().findType(generatedClass);

                // This is where the formating should be made. The code below currently format the selected file only.
                var commandId = IJavaEditorActionDefinitionIds.FORMAT;
                var handlerService = workbench.getService(IHandlerService.class);
                try
                {
                    handlerService.executeCommand(commandId, null);
                }
                catch (Exception e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            catch (JavaModelException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

    MessageDialog.openInformation(activeWorkbenchWindow.getShell(), "Generated bindings on files:", String.join(", ", generatedClasses));

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you can call `org.eclipse.jdt.core.ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter` to get an instance of `org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.CodeFormatter` to do formatting.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks, with ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter I can actually pass the formatter to my bindingGenerator class so the formatting is done at the same time as the code is modified. I like that but there is one problem. (See next comment)

Comment: @greg-449 With the code above, the plugin is actually calling the Eclipse "Format"  plugin handler which is the same as pressing "Format" in the Edit menu or right click->format on a selected file. It actually uses the Project's formatting configurations. I need that. When using ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter I need to specify the formatting options so it seems I would need to manually replicate the Project's formatting configurations into my formatter instance. Unless there is a way to use the project's formatting configurations?

Comment: `ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter` appears to load the current options using `JavaCore.getOptions()` if `options` argument is null

Comment: @greg-449 I've tried with null but it seems to use the default Eclipse options instead of the Project's. I am now looking at IJavaProject.getOptions(boolean inheritJavaCoreOptions) maybe I can pass the Project's options to the Formatter...

Comment: @greg-449 Hurray it works! Passing the projects options to the formatter works as intended. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @greg-449 for pointing me out to ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter.

I just need to create a formatter with the project's options like this:

```
ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(compilationUnit.getJavaProject().getOptions(true));
```

and then use the formatter on the file's sources.